# Creating "subforms" in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm pretty new to WPF and C#. I am looking to create multiple windows with in one primary window, like creating forms and subforms in Microsoft Access. I would like to work with One main .xaml and have two seprate .xaml's that the user will open with a button selection. I do not want to have multiple windows pop up (if possible). Instead I would like the main .xaml to display the selected .xaml with-in itself.

Answer (score 2):

Create a User Control and switch the visualization, more examples: http://windowsclient.net/learn/video.aspx?v=76360

Comment: I know this is an old answer, but the link no longer exists to a valid video.  is there another link to the content?

Answer (score 0):

You can user user controlls for this. This is a good walkthrough http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/UserControl.aspx

Answer (score 0):

As the other individuals have said, you'll want to create a User Control.  It's fairly good practice to create User Controls where possible if you'll be re-using the code.